# port aggregation on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, port, aggregation

I have to detect port aggregation configuration on Linux.

Supposing that the ifcfg-* files were not updated (configuration was done with ifenslave only), how can I understand which eth? devices are slaves to which bond? devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it:

> ip addr

eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast **master bond0** qlen 1000